# python re.sub, only replace part of match

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am very new to python

I need to match all cases by one regex expression and do a replacement. this is a sample substring --> desired result:

```
<cross_sell id="123" sell_type="456"> --> <cross_sell>
```

i am trying to do this in my code:

```
myString = re.sub(r'\<[A-Za-z0-9_]+(\s[A-Za-z0-9_="\s]+)', "", myString)
```

instead of replacing everything after `<cross_sell`, it replaces everything and just returns `'>'`

is there a way for re.sub to replace only the capturing group instead of the entire pattern?

Comment: Is the input data XML? Thanks.

Comment: i am reading an xml file and putting it in a string

Comment: what if i want my output as    <mystring id="123" sell_type="456">    i.e i want to replace cross_cell with mystring

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use substitution groups:

```
>>> my_string = '<cross_sell id="123" sell_type="456"> --> <cross_sell>'
>>> re.sub(r'(\<[A-Za-z0-9_]+)(\s[A-Za-z0-9_="\s]+)', r"\1", my_string)
'<cross_sell> --> <cross_sell>'
```

Notice I put the first group (the one you want to keep) in parenthesis and then I kept that in the output by using the `"\1"` modifier (first group) in the replacement string.

Comment: beautiful answer!

Comment: what if i want my output as    <mystring id="123" sell_type="456">    i.e i want to replace cross_cell with mystring

Answer (score 3):

You can use a group reference to match the first word and a negated character class to match the rest of the string between `<>` :

```
>>> s='<cross_sell id="123" sell_type="456">'
>>> re.sub(r'(\w+)[^>]+',r'\1',s)
'<cross_sell>'
```

`\w` is equal to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Comment: Good call on the `\w+`.

Comment: Couldn't it be simplified to `re.sub(r'(\w+)[^>]+',r'\1',s)`?

Comment: @maccinza Indeed, nice!

Comment: @maccinza -- For the input text, it can be simplified ... However, I'm not sure you would want to make that substitution in general... (who knows what the content of the tag looks like?)

Answer (score 1):

Since the input data is XML, you'd better parse it with an *XML parser*.

Built-in [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is one option:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> data = '<cross_sell id="123" sell_type="456"></cross_sell>'
>>> cross_sell = ET.fromstring(data)
>>> cross_sell.attrib = {}
>>> ET.tostring(cross_sell)
'<cross_sell />'
```

[`lxml.etree`](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) is an another option.

Answer (score 1):

below code tested under python 3.6 , without use group..

```
test = '<cross_sell id="123" sell_type="456">'
resp = re.sub(r'\w+="\w+"' ,r'',test)
print (resp)

<cross_sell>
```